# WP query taxonomy optimization

Tags: posts, wp-query, taxonomy, mysql

Is there any way to speed this query? Noob here.

```
 SELECT wp_posts.ID
    FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 1=1
    AND ( wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (9,11) )
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,151,152,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,177,178,179,181,182,183,184,185,187,191,192,195,677,678,679,680,681,682,683,684,685,686,687,688,689,690,691,692,693,694,695,696,697,698,699,701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710,711,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,719,721,724,726,728,729,742,743,744,747,750,758,759,760,781) )
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 0, 6
```

I'm using query monitor and this is from homepage of site. I think this is reading from Menu, because there is a lot categories and subcategories in there. Any chance I can change this query to load more optimized?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the `WP_Query`?

Comment: where did this query come from and where is the PHP code that generated it? I notice there's a hyper-expensive random order parameter, but without the PHP code that generated this it's near impossible to answer the question. Use the edit link under the tags to modify your question to include the missing information